# How to deploy an angular 6 application in production

Tags: angular, nginx, deployment

I have an `Angular 6` application production ready code, and ubuntu on EC2 Instance.I am deploying for the first time in production.

I am not able to get complete procedure for running angular application. 
I have used 
  `ng build --prod` command but still the application is not running in the background.

Step that I followed:

1) In `var/www/html/app_name$ ng build --prod` 
   a dist folder is created and application compiled without errors.

2) In nginx server I am setting up configuration files as

```
server {     
  listen 80;      
  listen [::]:80;      
  server_name http://site-name.com;      
  root /var/www/angular-app-name/dist;   
  server_tokens off;   
  index index.html index.htm;
  location / {         
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;      
  }
}
```

after this when i check my browser it says *site cannot be reached*

Is there any other method needs to be followed after `ng build --prod` ?
or server configuration needs to be changed.

Is any changes required in `package.json` file?

Comment: Do you see the nginx page? Is nginx running?

Comment: Yes, its showing 403 forbidden.